# calculating total floor size (Python)

Tags: python

I need to calculate the total floor size. it first asks for number of rooms(all are rectangular) and then using a for loop asks for length and width of each one. Here's my code(python):

```
norooms = int(input('How many rooms does the floor have?'))
length = dict()
width = dict()
for i in range(norooms):
    length[i] = input('what is the length of room?')
    width[i] =input('what is the width of room?')
    print('that was room number:',i+1)
```

Now ill have to calculate the total of the floor. Can I get some help?

Comment: do you really need `dict`?

Comment: This is really, really, *really* basic maths. You have made no attempt to even try to calculate the total floor area, so why should anyone want to do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
norooms = int(input('How many rooms does the floor have?'))
length = dict()
width = dict()
for i in range(norooms):
    length[i] = input('what is the length of room?')
    width[i] =input('what is the width of room?')
    print('that was room number:',i+1)
total=0
for i in range(norooms):
    total += float(length[i])*float(width[i])

print 'total is:' ,total
```

If it was in [Programming Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) I recommend this code instead:

```
room_counts = int(input('How many rooms does the floor have?'))
total=0
for i in xrange(room_counts)
    length=float(input('room #%s length?'%(i+1)))
    width=float(input('room #%s width?'%(i+1)))
    total +=length*width
print 'total is ',total
```

Comment: This `total=total+float(length[i])*float(width[i])` can be changed this `total += float(length[i])*float(width[i])` and don't answer a question with just code add some nots

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to calculate the area of a given room `x`? Do it for all of the rooms and then calculate the sum. Also be aware that currently the length and width of the rooms are still strings.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved very quickly with `numpy`. If you are going to do similar things in the future, it might be worth spending some time learning the library.

Anyways, here you go:

```
import numpy as np

no_rooms = int(input('How many rooms does the floor have?'))

length = np.empty(no_rooms)
width = np.empty(no_rooms)

for i in range(no_rooms):
    length[i] = input('what is the length of room?')
    width[i] = input('what is the width of room?')
    print('that was room number:', i+1)

print('total is: ' + str(np.dot(length, width)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop also iterates over the keys of dictionaries, so you can do:

```
for key in length:
    # do something with length[key] and width[key]
```

However, I would think that this would be a bit more readable if you changed your `dict`s to a `list` of `dict`s like so:

```
norooms = int(input('How many rooms does the floor have?'))
rooms = []
for i in range(norooms):
    room = {"length": 0, "width": 0}
    room["length"] = input('what is the length of room?')
    room["width"] = input('what is the width of room?')
    rooms.append(room)
    print('that was room number:',i+1)
for room in rooms:
    # do something with room["length"] and room["width"]
```

Or even just do the calculation in the first `for` loop, if you wish.